# Create a field base on the lookup field data

Tags: administration, lookup, formula-field, roll-up-summary, setup

Good day everyone,

Suppose I have an object "SAMPLE_OBJECT__c" which has a lookup field to "Accounts" object and it also has a another field which is "Value__c". Now what I want to accomplished is that I want to create a field in "Accounts" which is the total of my SAMPLE_OBJECT__c.Value__c from the last month. Is it possible ? If yes what are the possible thing I can do to make it possible. Please help I really need this functionality.

Thanks...

Comment: With a lookup you will have to use a trigger/ or batch to populate the data

Comment: Do you want data for each month to be stored or just last month is fine?

Comment: @AmitBangad last month is fine.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to aggregate on Value field of Sample_object__c (last month date) and store aggregate value at account level. You can achieve it by creating an Apex scheduler/ batch, wherein you can query all records of "Sample_object__c" which are of last month and are related to same account and store aggregate value at Account level.

Refer this article to know more about Apex Schedulers:- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: How can I call this scheduler ? I've tried to create one and then and i've tried to call but nothing happens ?

Comment: You can schedule a scheduler class from Salesforce ui (Setup> Build> Develop> Apex Classes) and click on "Schedule apex".

Also, you can schedule schdedulable class from apex by invoking "System.schedule" method.

Refer:- http://sfdccloudcomputing.blogspot.com/2014/01/different-ways-to-run-schedule-class.html